# Subset data/choosing data that fulfills a condition

Tags: r, windows

How can create a subset from the data ToothGrowth

```
    len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2  11.5   VC  0.5
3   7.3   VC  0.5
    ...
29 23.3   VC  2.0
30 29.5   VC  2.0
31 15.2   OJ  0.5
32 21.5   OJ  0.5
    . . .
58 27.3   OJ  2.0
59 29.4   OJ  2.0
60 23.0   OJ  2.0
```

by choosing all records where dose supplement type (supp )is OJ and assign them to variable ans?

I tried this:

```
ans <- ToothGrowth[ToothGrowth$supp=="OJ"]
```

and this:

```
ans <- ToothGrowth[ToothGrowth$supp=="OJ",]
```

but apparently neither of those are correct.

I would be really grateful for advice.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I need ones with supp=OJ.

Comment: So I tried      "ans <- ToothGrowth[ToothGrowth$supp=="OJ",]" but it didn't do the job.

Comment: @TapioAhonen please share `str()` of `ToothGrowth`.

Comment: @MKR `str()` is `'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ len : num  4.2 11.5 7.3 5.8 6.4 10 11.2 11.2 5.2 7 ...
 $ supp: Factor w/ 2 levels "OJ","VC": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ dose: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...`

Comment: The assignment as explained by you is expected result. e.g: ans<- ToothGrowth[TootheGrowth$supp == "OJ",]. Now print ans to revew the results.